# How to change log level to DEBUG within stormcrawler SDK?

Tags: java, slf4j, apache-storm, stormcrawler

I see that SLF4J is used for logging entries during stormcrawler components execution. However I cannot find the file containing the configuration used for SLF4J logging. Do I need a separate configuration file to enable debug level logging?

Comment: are you running StormCrawler in local  mode or deployed on a Storm cluster?

Comment: This question was for getting the DEBUG log entries within eclipse console